# How can i remove Python modues from Linux in centos

Tags: python, centos

I am getting ths error

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul  2 2013, 13:33:13)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    (version_info, _mysql.version_info))
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

Now i dont know how i have installed that. i treid so many things like yum , pip easy, install etc.

how can i remove all versions of `MysqlDB` FROM THERE

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Mac (Lion 10.7.5). I just linked the libmysqlclient.18 like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

I hope it helps